# Ajax success: returned array is always false

Tags: php, arrays, ajax

Via JSON (and php) in a mySQL table I find all datasets that match a given keyword. I then want to use the urls in the returned array to append to an HTML element.

```
$.ajax({
        url:    'actions/del_and_find_pixa_keywords.php',
        type:   'POST',
        data:   {
            keyword: pixaKeyword.val()              
        },
        success: function(data){
            pixaSearchResults.empty();
            data.forEach(function(i,v){
                pixaSearchResults.append('<a href="'+v.preview_url+'" target="_blank"><img src="'+v.large_img_url+'" alt="'+v.keyword+'" class="fn_pixaImgResults cms_width100" data-large-url=""></a>');
            });


        },
        error: function(){
            alert("an error occurred");
        }
    });
```

This is the php bit:

```
$keyword = $_POST['keyword']??false;

if ($keyword){
    // return keywords and urls
    $results = find_matching_keywords($keyword);
    return($results);
}
```

The SQL query works. If I echo it as a foreach loop in the PHP above and then console.log it in the ajax success i can see the content of the array.

With the ajax and php code above I get an error in the console saying:

```
Uncaught TypeError: data.forEach is not a function
```

But I would need the data as an array to be able to loop through it as in the $.ajax code above.

Comment: are you sure `data` is an array? could you dump it to `console.log(data)` perhaps?

Comment: `dataType: "json"` needs to be in your AJAX request, and you need to return `json_encode($results);`

Comment: @BagusTesa i returns nothing (empty string i suppose)

Comment: @GROVER. thank you, it now goes to ajax error, if I alert xhr.status it returns 200

Comment: I alert this:
`error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
`alert(thrownError)
`}
and then get: SyntaxError: unexpected end of JSON input

Comment: For PHP to respond with JSON, you need to write it to the output buffer, eg `header('Content-type: application/json'); echo json_encode($results); exit;`

Comment: so i added this: `header('Content-type:application/json');echo json_encode($results); exit; but keep going to ajax error